# Endeca Forge Process

Tags: sql, forge, endeca

I am using queries.xml file which contains 5 sql statements.
I would like to know if the 5 sql queries are executed at the same time or one sql query at a time when running the forge process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries are executed one at a time as the file is processed. Also, the file is processed top down.